Hardhat, problem with uninstalled dependencies
I can compile my contracts successfully.
I had some problems with some of the hardhat functions so i installed Waffle and its dependencies.
However it doesn't work and throws an error stating missing dependencies.
What may be wrong and how to solve that ?
C:\Users\eliya\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\My_decentrilize_Uber\scripts\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js:169
        throw new errors_1.HardhatError(errors_list_1.ERRORS.PLUGINS.MISSING_DEPENDENCIES, {
        ^

HardhatError: HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers requires the following dependencies to be installed: @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition, @nomicfoundation/ignition-core.
Please run: npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition@^0.15.4" "@nomicfoundation/ignition-core@^0.15.4"
    at analyzeModuleNotFoundError (C:\Users\eliya\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\My_decentrilize_Uber\scripts\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js:169:15)
    at loadConfigAndTasks (C:\Users\eliya\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\My_decentrilize_Uber\scripts\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js:69:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\eliya\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\My_decentrilize_Uber\scripts\node_modules\hardhat\internal\lib\hardhat-lib.js:30:84)     
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\eliya\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\My_decentrilize_Uber\scripts\deploy.js:1:17) {
  parent: undefined,
  _stack: 'HardhatError: HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers requires the following dependencies to be installed: @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition, @nomicfoundation/ignition-core.\n' +
    'Please run: npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition@^0.15.4" "@nomicfoundation/ignition-core@^0.15.4"\n' +
    '    at analyzeModuleNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\eliya\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\My_decentrilize_Uber\\scripts\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\core\\config\\config-loading.js:169:15)\n' +
    '    at loadConfigAndTasks (C:\\Users\\eliya\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\My_decentrilize_Uber\\scripts\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\core\\config\\config-loading.js:69:9)\n' +
    '    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\eliya\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\My_decentrilize_Uber\\scripts\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\lib\\hardhat-lib.js:30:84)\n' +
    '    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)\n' +
    '    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)\n' +
    '    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)\n' +
    '    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)\n' +
    '    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)\n' +
    '    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)\n' +
    '    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\eliya\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\My_decentrilize_Uber\\scripts\\deploy.js:1:17)',
  errorDescriptor: {
    number: 801,
    message: 'Plugin %plugin% requires the following dependencies to be installed: %missingDependencies%.\n' +
      'Please run: npm install --save-dev %missingDependenciesVersions%',
    title: 'Plugin dependencies not installed',
    description: 'You are trying to use a plugin with unmet dependencies.\n' +
      '\n' +
      "Please follow Hardhat's instructions to resolve this.",
    shouldBeReported: false
  },
  number: 801,
  messageArguments: {
    plugin: '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers',
    missingDependencies: '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition, @nomicfoundation/ignition-core',
    missingDependenciesVersions: '"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition@^0.15.4" "@nomicfoundation/ignition-core@^0.15.4"'
  },
  _isHardhatError: true
}

Node.js v20.11.0


As the error is self-explanatory, there are some required packages to work with hardhat ignition.
Run npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition@^0.15.4" "@nomicfoundation/ignition-core@^0.15.4", and it should work ideally.
